# Setting up IIS on EC2 with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm in the process of learning how to utilise AWS and its resources. Currently trying to set up IIS on an EC2 instance using CloudFormation in JSON format. I'm unsure of my `userData` segment and whether I may be missing anything in the other segments for an IIS EC2 instance. When I deploy this script using cloudFormation, a stack is created successfully however, testing the remote desktop of the resulting instance ends with a crash, what could be the reason for that?

My code-

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

"Description": "CloudFormation template for EC2 instance with web server",

"Parameters": {
    "InstanceType": {
        "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "t2.micro",
        "AllowedValues": ["t2.micro"],
        "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid EC2 instance."
    },

    "VpcId": {
        "Description": "VPC id",
        "Type": "String"
    },

    "InstanceSubnetId": {
        "Description": "Subnet id where instance would be hosted",
        "Type": "String"
    },

    "KeyName": {
        "Description": "Name of existing EC2 key-pair to enable SSH access to the instance",
        "Type": "String",
        "ConstraintDescription": "Must be the name of an existing EC2 keypair"
    },

    "SSHLocation": {
        "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to EC2 instances",
        "Type": "String",
        "MinLength": "9",
        "MaxLength": "18",
        "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
        "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."

    }
},

"Mappings": {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch":{
        "t2.micro": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        }
    },
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
        "eu-west-1": {
            "HVM64": "ami-08eeb5a90cf59a66a"
        },
        "eu-west-2": {
            "HVM64": "ami-08eeb5a90cf59a66a"
        },
        "eu-west-3": {
            "HVM64": "ami-08eeb5a90cf59a66a"
        }
    }
},

"Resources": {
    "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties":{
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "VpcId"
            },

            "GroupDescription" : "Allow access from HTTP and SSH traffic",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"    
                },

                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": {
                        "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                    }
                }
            ]
            
        }
    },
    
    "WebServerEC2Instance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "configSets": {
                    "All": [
                        "ConfigureSampleApp"
                    ]
                },
                "ConfigureSampleApp": {
                    "packages": {
                        "yum": {
                            "httpd": []
                        }
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                            "content": { 
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "\n",
                                    [
                                        "<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            "mode": "000644",
                            "owner": "root",
                            "group": "root"
                        }
                    },

                    "services": {
                        "sysvinit": {
                            "httpd": { 
                                "enabled": "true", 
                                "ensureRunning" : "true" 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
        },
        
        "Properties": {
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },

            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "KeyName"
            },

            "ImageId": {
                "Fn::FindInMap": [
                    "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::FindInMap": [
                            "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                            {
                                "Ref": "InstanceType"
                            },
                            "Arch"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },

            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "Description": "Primary network interface",
                    "DeviceIndex": "0",
                    "SubnetId": {
                        "Ref": "InstanceSubnetId"
                    },
                    "GroupSet": [
                        {
                            "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],

            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                            "yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                            "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                            "         --stack ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            },

                            "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                            "         --configsets All ",
                            "         --region ",

                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            "\n",
                            "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                            "         --stack ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            },
                            "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                            "         --region ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            "\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is your EC2 machine linux or windows? Linux machines don't have IIS.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Ah yes, sorry I didn't specify. It's windows.

Comment: You might want to check if it is really windows instance.. Windows server do not support SSH. they support remote login via 3389 port. Also locations such as `/var/www/html/` and `yum` command not supported windows. Or I am missing something big.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah, the ami I'm using is windows based. I built my template using an example as a reference. I assumed the SSH parameter is functionality that was added in for cases where the ami is linux based. Given that the ami aspect is also parameterised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `SSHLocation` parameter should be discarded as that's relevant when setting up a linux instance. Wherever it's referenced, `0.0.0.0/0` serves as a suitable replacement.

Setting up your Windows instance with IIS can be done with this `UserData` configuration which makes use of Powershell and not bash which is based on linux.

```
"UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "<powershell>\n",
                            "Add-WindowsFeature Web-WebServer -includeAllSubFeature -logpath $env:temp\\Web-WebServer_feature.log \n",
                            "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Tools -includeAllSubFeature -logpath $env:temp\\Web-Mgmt-Tools_feature.log \n",
                            
                            "remove-website -name \"Default Web Site\" \n",
                            "new-website -name site -port 80 -physicalpath C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot -ApplicationPool \".NET v4.5\" -force \n",
                            "</powershell>\n",
                            "<script>\n",
                            "cfn-init.exe -v -c setup -s ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                            },
                            " -r WebServerLC",
                            " --region ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            "\n",
                            "cfn-signal.exe -e %ERRORLEVEL% \"",
                            "\"",
                            "</script>\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
```